# Update records stored in array in other record

Tags: javascript, surrealdb

I have the following record-structures shown in JSON/Typescript format:

```
(tablename = dimension)
interface Dimension {
    name: string,
    units: Unit[]
}

(tablename = unit)
interface Unit {
    symbol: string,
    is_base: boolean,
}
```

I want to change the property `is_base` to `false` on all units within a dimension in one query. How do i do this? I am using [surrealdb.wasm](https://github.com/surrealdb/surrealdb.wasm) in a Javascript project (I believe this uses [Indxdb](https://github.com/surrealdb/indxdb)).

I have tried the following query:

```
UPDATE dimension:myDimensionID.units.* SET is_base = false
```

And the query seems to execute successfully, but it does not change the property `is_base` on any unit record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Record links don't currently work on update statements, so you can't change the value of a linked table.

If embedding units you can do this

```
create dimension:test content {
name: "stuff",
units : [{is_base: true}, {is_base: true}]
};

UPDATE dimension:test SET units.is_base = false;
```

If units are a separate table, you can do this if you have a field of which dimension it belongs to.

```
update unit 
SET is_base = false
WHERE dimension = "dimension:test"
```

Comment: I forgot all about me posting this question, but i found out and ended up using the second example. The first example is how i initially structured it, so thanks for the answer on that one!